# std::type_identity to support several variadic argument lists

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++20, parameter-pack

`std::type_identity` can be used to provide non-deducible context. So, I wondered if it will work on a deduced variadic list. But different compilers give different results.
https://godbolt.org/z/4cfqbxdeo

```
#include <type_traits>
 
struct in_between{};

template <typename... T>
struct args_tag
{
    using type = std::common_type_t<T...>;
};

template <typename... T>
void bar(args_tag<T...>, std::type_identity_t<T>..., int, std::type_identity_t<T>...) {}

template <typename... T>
void bar(args_tag<T...>, std::type_identity_t<T>..., in_between, std::type_identity_t<T>...) {}

// example
int main() {
    bar(args_tag<int, int>{}, 4, 8, 15, 16, 23);
    bar(args_tag<int, int>{}, 4, 8, in_between{}, 16, 23);
}
```

The first one compiles with gcc and msvc.

```
bar(args_tag<int, int>{}, 4, 8, 15, 16, 23);
```

The second one compiles only with msvc.

```
bar(args_tag<int, int>{}, 4, 8, in_between{}, 16, 23);
```

What should be the behavior according to the standard?

Comment: So your final question is why `bar(args_tag<int, int>{}, 4, 8, in_between{}, 16, 23)` doesn't compile right?

Comment: Packs don't do this kind of complex deductions. They are greedy, the first pack will try to consume all remaining arguments when being deduced.

Comment: Also your program [won't compile](https://godbolt.org/z/4qM3ErfvP) **with clang** even without the `bar(args_tag<int, int>{}, 4, 8, in_between{}, 16, 23)`

Comment: @user12002570 yes. It compiles with int

Comment: @user12002570 you should have added "...with clang". Your link shows GCC and msvc compile it

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I know that, but `std::type_identity` should prevent such deduction, shouldn't it? It works in 2 examples. Maybe this should be a language lawyer question, because read my disclaimer

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik I think you should first check the code with all compilers. So there are basically two questions here. First why `bar(args_tag<int, int>{}, 4, 8, in_between{}, 16, 23)` and second why clang rejects `bar(args_tag<int, int>{}, 4, 8, 15, 16, 23)`. Also note msvc [compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/Ehzj6n5Tb) `bar(args_tag<int, int>{}, 4, 8, in_between{}, 16, 23)`

Comment: @user12002570 should I change it to language lawyer then?

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik You should simplify your question be removing most of the code and including only that is necessary for to reproduce the problem. Like see [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/133b5YK8G)

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik Yes, add tag `language-lawyer` and more importantly I would suggest reducing the code as I have done in my [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/133b5YK8G) so that we can focus on answering for one call `bar(args_tag<int, int>{}, 4, 8, in_between{}, 16, 23)` without worrying about other calls. This is because **different compilers are giving different results for different calls** so just making this more concise by asking about one call at a time. Then separate question can be asked for different calls(if the answers provided here does not answer that)

Comment: I think the program should compile for both calls. And msvc is the only right one here.

Comment: Looks like gcc and clang bug to me. Both calls should work fine afaik.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strange compilation errors when instantiating a variadic function template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72602548/strange-compilation-errors-when-instantiating-a-variadic-function-template)

Comment: @WeijunZhou well, I don't know. The question is very similar (I would say it's the same), but I don't think the answer is complete. For instance: `T...` is clearly deduced, it is not within the non-deduced context. Also: I don't think the compiler can connect the `sizeof...(T)` with the number of function arguments in the packs. But does it need to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program is **well-formed** for both the calls for the following reason(s).  In the given example, deduction is performed only using the first function parameter `args_tag<T...>`. The remaining two parameter packs
won't be involved in deduction since they are in non-deduced context. After the **deduction** is performed using the first parameter `args_tag<T...>`, the deduced `T` is **substituted** into the remaining two parameter packs as per [temp.deduc.general#3](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.general#5.sentence-4). This means that for the call `bar(args_tag<int, int>{}, 4, 8, 15, 16, 23)`, `T` **gets deduced** as `{int, int}`. Now for each of the args in this list `{int, int}`, we get a corresponding `std::type_identity` parameter(4 in total because there are two `std::type_identity` parameter and `T` has two `int`s) as shown in the below declaration. Essentially, the declaration becomes:

```
template <>
//--------------------------vvv--vvv--->deduced from first argument
void bar<int, int>(args_tag<int, int>,
//-----------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv-->gets fixed/substituted when first argument is supplied 
                   std::type_identity_t<int>,std::type_identity_t<int>,
                   int, 
//-----------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv-->gets fixed/substituted when first argument is supplied 
                   std::type_identity_t<int>,std::type_identity_t<int>) {}
```

Now as we can see, this is **viable** for the call `bar(args_tag<int, int>{}, 4, 8, 15, 16, 23)` and so should succeed.

This can be seen from [temp.deduct.general#3](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.general#5.sentence-4):

> **When all template arguments have been deduced or obtained from default template arguments, all uses of template parameters in the template parameter list of the template are replaced with the corresponding deduced** or default argument values.
> If the substitution results in an invalid type, as described above, type deduction fails.
> If the function template has associated constraints ([temp.constr.decl]), those constraints are checked for satisfaction ([temp.constr.constr]). If the constraints are not satisfied, type deduction fails.
> In the context of a function call, if type deduction has not yet failed, then for those function parameters for which the function call has arguments, each function parameter with a type that was non-dependent before substitution of any explicitly-specified template arguments is checked against its corresponding argument; if the corresponding argument cannot be implicitly converted to the parameter type, type deduction fails.

(emphasis mine)

---

That is, **gcc and clang are wrong in giving a diagnostic**. See also the [contrived example](https://godbolt.org/z/4Gxracazf) at the end to make this more clear.

---

This also explains why a call such as `bar(args_tag<int, int, double>{}, 4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 34,34);` passes while the call `bar(args_tag<int, int, double>{}, 4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 34)` fails in all compilers.

```
bar(args_tag<int, int, double>{}, 4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 34, 34); //valid because `T={int, int, double}` means the second and fourth packs can each get three arguments 
bar(args_tag<int, int, double>{}, 4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 34); //fails
```

---

##### Contrived Example

To make the above explanation more clear, below is a contrived example showing the logic/reasoning. Note that the example illustrates what should be happening in your program(both calls should compile).

```
#include <type_traits>
 
template <typename... T>
struct args_tag{  };

template <typename... T>
void bar(args_tag<T...>, std::type_identity_t<T>...) {}

// example
int main() {
    bar(args_tag<int, int>{}, 4, 8); //valid because T={int, int} and exactly two extra  args are provided
    bar(args_tag<int, int, int>{}, 4, 8, 6); //valid because T={int, int, int} and exactly three extra args are provided
    //bar(args_tag<int, int>{}, 4);  //invalid because because T={int, int} but only one extra arg is provided 
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4Gxracazf)

---

[GCC rejects valid program involving parameter packs with in between class type](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=113443)

[Clang rejects valid program involving parameter packs with in between type](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/78449)

Comment: Hmm, some quotes from the standard would be nice.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I agree, I am looking for the appropriate quote. Meanwhile I've posted the explanation. Basically, we need to find the quote/reference for the contrived example.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat As also said in the asnwer, the best as of now I could come with is that `T` is deduced(to say `{int, int}`) and then it is substituted for each arg in `T` in `std::type_identity`. Then this results in a viable candidate. And so the call should succeed.

Comment: Is the number of function args in a pack counted during deduction? Like `T... args`: the compiler can see the connection with `T...`, but with `type_identity_t<T>... args`? What if it needs to count `args`, but it hasn't finished the deduction step. Just a thought

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik Each "call argument" is used to help deduce a template parameter(if the template parameter is in a deduced context). The number of args should not matter. Substitution happens after deduction.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I've added a reference [temp.deduct.general#3](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.general#5.sentence-4) that I think should apply here.